# How to set Lable Text with Text field input

Tags: xcode, cocoa, text, field

So, In Xcode Cocoa Im trying to make an app that when you type something in a text field, It will pop up on a Lable saying the exact samething. I've been trying to find out how to make it work for a day now, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `value` of both fields—for they are both fields—to the same property of the same object.

You can find the `value` binding in the Bindings Inspector when either field is selected. Remember to bind both of them, and to the same property of the same object. Of course, also don't forget to create that property.